# Does anyone know what font this is? Or any fully connected font similar to this?

Tags: fonts

[image: The fully connected font]

Hi everyone,

Does anyone know where I can find a fully connected font like the one I've shown here? I'll need it to do a Fourier series decomposition so I can make a epicycle animation.

Please let me know, It'll be of huge help!

Comment: Please follow [our font identification guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is probably not a font but you can make it yourself:

*Edit- using Adobe Illustrator for this*

1. Choose any font and type your text
2. Adjust type and line spacing as desired
3. Type> Create Outlines
4. Object> Ungroup
5. Object> Compound Path> Make
6. Select and Delete inner letter holes (in the A, O, P, etc.) if desired
7. Draw the "connector rectangle"
8. Select both Compound Path and Rectangle
9. Window> Pathfinder> Unite
10. Adjust Stroke and Fill colors as desired

[image]

Comment: Hi Kyle! Thank you so much!! Yeah, I'll be able to recreate this!